# error java.lang.ClassNotFoundException when try to use OneWayAnova Class

Tags: java, eclipse, math

I'm using eclipse RCP (helios), and I need to add statistics functions.

In the editor, I have no problem, no error.

But when I run or debug the project, I get:

```
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: 
org.apache.commons.math3.stat.descriptive.SummaryStatistics error.
```

first question, the library says si java 1.5+ compatible, I'm running on 1.6.
is this ok?

besides build path... is there any other way to set classpath ?

Best Regards

Comment: Is the Apache Commons Math-3 library on your classpath?

Comment: Show us the full command line that is running when you try to run it

Comment: hi @RoddyoftheFrozenPeas, I got it... I wasn't aware of this config in manifest.mf.. Bundle-ClassPath:, when I add the library to that config/manifest item, it works! Is confusing that everything compiles ok, but when you run... doesn't work.Eclipse has there own rules!